# Cannot Install Or Run Ubuntu From USB Stick - Boots But Then Get Errors & Black Screen

Tags: boot, grub2, usb

tI m trying to install Ubuntu on a Gigabyte Brix GB-BKi3A-7100, I ve been using Ubuntu for 12 years and I ve lost count of the number of computers I ve installed it on, but I ve never had so many problems I can barely boot, I get the usual menu screen but after about 8 seconds it shows the errors :

`unpacking failed: Decoding failed

01c.0: AER: PCIe Bus error: severity corrected, type=Physical Layer (Receiver ID)

01c.0: AER:   device [8006:9d10] error status/mask=0000000/00002000

01c.0: AER:    [ 0] RxErr'

(apologies for the first few digits before "01c0." not being present).
After 2 seconds I then get a black screen and thats it, no boot, nothing. I ve extensively googled it and tried all sorts of things including adding "pci=noaer" "pci=nomsi", making various changes in the BIOS, I ve tried so many things but nothing works. nomsi and nonaer do get me further in that I dont get the lines of errors I got initially, but I get a 1 line error - something about intrams not being able to decode something and then a black screen and nothing. Getting nowhere and fed up so thought I d seek some help.

Comment: No - it does boot, but pretty soon after I get errors and a black screen

Comment: Its very hard to select anything as the menu disappears so fast, but I selected safe graphics mode and managed to install Ubuntu . . . but theres no picture when I boot the pc. I know what to do once the system has booted to make it permanently boot with nomodeset or install proprietory drivers, but I cant get it to boot to be able to make the changes.

Comment: The Brix is UEFI, so I pressed "Esc" to get into recovery but pressing it just gets me into a Grub screen with "GNU Grub 2.04" at the top and nothing below it save multiple entries of "Esc.>" (probably due to the fact that my monitor shuts the screen down a tenth of a second after theres no signal, meaning I m pressing "Esc" blindly) theres no script for me to modify to make it nomoeset and typing "nomodeset" or "quiet splash nomodeset" just results in errors.

Comment: I did not say that it doesnt boot or that it only boots a certain a percentage - it boots then I quickly get a black screen. I ve managed to get into safe graphics mode and install Ubuntu, now I get a black screen straight away, see above comment.